# how to completely disable Hibernate exceptions within Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, openjpa

I have a situation. I'm creating a Spring Boot project to interact with a bunch of legacy OpenJPA Entities.

The issue is that, because Spring Boot Starter Data JPA uses Hibernate as a base, the Spring application throws Hibernate exceptions like:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]
: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Using default @DiscriminatorValue for a discriminator of type CHAR is not safe
```

Now, **while this can easily be fixed by updating the Entity code, we are unable to touch or change that code**. We have to leave it as is - not up to Hibernate standards.

So, is there *any* way, within Spring, to disable Hibernate exceptions like this, so we can accept Entities that don't conform to Hibernate's standards and throw Hibernate exceptions?

Our code design is simple, a standard Service-Repository setup. For example:

PersonRepository.java:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    Person findFirstByPersonSsnSsn(String ssn);

    Person findFirstByPersonId(Integer personId);

}
```

PersonDomainService.java:

```
public interface PersonDomainService {

    Person findPersonBySsn(String ssn); 

    public Person findPerson(Integer id);
}
```

PersonDomainServiceImpl.java:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonDomainServiceImpl implements PersonDomainService {

    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public PersonDomainServiceImpl(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Person findPersonBySsn(String ssn) {
        Person person = personRepository.findFirstByPersonSsnSsn(ssn);

        System.out.println(person.getAddresses().size());
        System.out.println(person.getPhones().size());

        return person;

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public Person findPerson(Integer id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Person person = personRepository.findFirstByPersonId(id);

        System.out.println(person.getAddresses().size());
        System.out.println(person.getPhones().size());

        return person;
    }   
}
```

And the Entities are pretty standard:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON", schema = "SCHEMA")
public class Person implements Serializable, EntityWithAuditInfo {
...
```

Comment: there is a way to do so in spring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172870/where-and-how-handle-springhibernate-exceptions

Comment: let me know in case your requirement is something different than the things stated

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that hibernate refuses to initialize itself, so this is not an exception handling problem, but you'd have to somehow persuade hibernate to initialize even though it feels that discriminator is "dangerous".

Searching [hibernate's source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) reveals this exception is [thrown at](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ae890b46234d615675dcef00093a72531482b822/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/EntityBinder.java#L472)

```
public void bindDiscriminatorValue() {
    if ( StringHelper.isEmpty( discriminatorValue ) ) {
        Value discriminator = persistentClass.getDiscriminator();
        if ( discriminator == null ) {
            persistentClass.setDiscriminatorValue( name );
        }
        else if ( "character".equals( discriminator.getType().getName() ) ) {
            throw new AnnotationException(
                    "Using default @DiscriminatorValue for a discriminator of type CHAR is not safe"
            );
        }
        else if ( "integer".equals( discriminator.getType().getName() ) ) {
            persistentClass.setDiscriminatorValue( String.valueOf( name.hashCode() ) );
        }
        else {
            persistentClass.setDiscriminatorValue( name ); //Spec compliant
        }
    }
    else {
        //persistentClass.getDiscriminator()
        persistentClass.setDiscriminatorValue( discriminatorValue );
    }
}
```

As you can see, hibernate will always throw such an exception if a discriminatorValue is not provided for a discriminator of type char. There is no way to prevent that short of changing the source code for hibernate.

This method [is invoked from](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ae890b46234d615675dcef00093a72531482b822/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/EntityBinder.java#L263):

```
public void bindEntity() {
    persistentClass.setAbstract( annotatedClass.isAbstract() );
    persistentClass.setClassName( annotatedClass.getName() );
    persistentClass.setJpaEntityName(name);
    //persistentClass.setDynamic(false); //no longer needed with the Entity name refactoring?
    persistentClass.setEntityName( annotatedClass.getName() );
    bindDiscriminatorValue();

    persistentClass.setLazy( lazy );
    if ( proxyClass != null ) {
        persistentClass.setProxyInterfaceName( proxyClass.getName() );
    }
    persistentClass.setDynamicInsert( dynamicInsert );
    persistentClass.setDynamicUpdate( dynamicUpdate );

    ... and 170 more lines of code to parse all other annotations in this class
}
```

As we can see from the absence of a catch block, hibernate aborts parsing that entity if the discriminator value can not be determined.

Therefore, even the most current version of hibernate can not be used with an entity that lacks a discriminator value when the discriminator is of type char. (BTW, there is an [open issue about this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5798) which hasn't been acted upon by the hibernate team for the last 7 years)

The only ways to resolve this are changing the entity, changing hibernate, or use another JPA implementation.

Comment: I believe this is, unfortunately, the most correct answer. Since we can't change the entity, and because changing Hibernate isn't wise, I'll have to use a different Spring JPA implementation.